# Slick slider настроить автоматическую прокрутку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

У slick слайдера если количество элементов меньше или столько же сколько должно отображаться, то скрываются стрелки и перестает работать автоматическая прокрутка, как это реализовать?
[Пример на codepen.io](https://codepen.io/Fess/pen/KeMGVY)

То что исчезают стрелки это не критично, но то что прокрутка больше не работает очень плохо.
Так как использую сдвоенный слайдер slick, если нет автоматической прокрутки у дотсов(второй слайдер) то не прокручивается и основной

Пример js, если выставить количество отображаемых слайдов 3(количество больше или равно сумме слайдов) то автопрокрутка отключится

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slidder1').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        asNavFor: '.slidder2',
    });

    $('.slidder2').slick({
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      asNavFor: '.slidder1',
      dots: true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    });

  });
```

Comment: Допишите сами условие, что если меньше или равно n, то пусть нажимаются слайды последовательно. Slick не настолько универсален.

Comment: Думал об этом, подскажите может у вас есть пример данной реализации?, чтобы не с нуля писать.

Comment: Пишите с нуля) Будут вопросы или проблемы, обновляйте свой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Согласен что решение очень топорное, но работает.
Смотрим на количество слайдов у слайдера отвечающего за навигацию и если их меньше заданного отменяем возможность улетать в бока, а раз не ломается этот слайдер то без проблем ставим автопрокрутку к первому.

JS

```
    $('.slider-front-nav').on('setPosition', function(event, slick){
      var length_slid = $('.slider-front-nav .slider-front-nav-unit.slick-slide').length;
      if (length_slid <= 4) {
        $('.slider-front-nav').addClass("stop-transform");  
      }else{
        $('.slider-front-nav').removeClass("stop-transform");
      }
    });
```

CSS

```
        .slider-front-nav.stop-transform .slick-track {
            transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) !important;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.slick-list, .slick-track{
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы решить проблему с отключением автоматической прокрутки, вы можете добавить условие, которое будет проверять, достаточно ли элементов для показа установленного количества слайдов. Если количество элементов меньше установленного значения, то автоматическая прокрутка не будет включена.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var slider1 = $('.slidder1');
  var slider2 = $('.slidder2');
  
  if (slider1.find('.slick-slide').length >= 1) {
    slider1.slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        asNavFor: '.slidder2',
    });
  }

  if (slider2.find('.slick-slide').length >= 2) {
    slider2.slick({
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      asNavFor: '.slidder1',
      dots: true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    });
  }
});
```